# Creating item in list using workflow doesn't trigger item created workflow

Tags: workflow

I create item inside list A using a workflow in list B, but the workflow in list A isn't triggered on item added, although if I create item in list A directly, it's launching the workflow.

This is 2010 environment, any help?

Comment: Is the created by on the item the System account?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue - Although I'm on SharePoint Online, I'm seeing similar behaviour, and the newly created items in List B are showing as being created by my username, and not a system account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the old "item created within the context of the System account doesn't fire workflow" problem.

Run the following PowerShell script to see if the flag is set or not.  If it's not set then this is very likely your problem.

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled
```

If it's not set run this:

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled = $true
$spWebService.Update()
```

Don't be fooled by the name of the property...it effects any method of inserting an item into a list via the System account.

I think there is a stsadm alternative to this if you're not comfortable with PowerShell...let me know, I can dig it up.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your answer, when the item is created using the workflow, the created by field is set to my username, not system account, so I think in this case it should start, what do you think?

Comment: Based on that I would have to say that my recommended solution probably won't address your problem.  And I only say probably because SharePoint has been known to have some odd behaviors.  It's obviously ideal if you can get it to kick off automatically, but you could also try something like this: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20Another%20Workflow&referringTitle=Home.  I've used this a lot in the past to kick off serial and parallel workflows.