# Create Item with powershell crush the execute of the workflow

Tags: powershell, designer-workflow

In the Sharepoint 2013 List, I created an item using Powershell. Once the item is created, the workflow is launched but it's cancelled then. I maked logs in the beginning of my workflow : "Log Current Item:ID to the workflow history list"
but Nothing in the history! He can't read the ID.

When i create the item manually via the button "New Item" of the list, every thing is ok and the workflow is completed.

Comment: Under which account did you run your powershell code?. Check that the powershell isn't running as a service account. Take a look at this thread. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100418/creating-item-in-list-using-workflow-doesnt-trigger-item-created-workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is : Just Run the script as a Normal User and Not "System account". We should verify the Last Modified in the Display Form of the item that it's not the System account.